# Graph Regularized Nonnegative Matrix Factorization for Data Representation | Why second order derivative of $F_{ab}$ is like this?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, graph-laplacian

Graph Regularized Nonnegative Matrix Factorization for Data Representation
[From [here]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5674058)

> [image]

**Doubt :** In equation $(28)$. Why the second order derivative of $F_{ab}$ is the form of the equation $(28)$? How to deduce subscripts $aa$ and $bb$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, they're hedging because they don't want to introduce the notion of 4th order tensors or [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) to deal with a matrix-by-matrix hessian.

Instead, they take the *matrix*-valued gradient which they've calculated as 
$$F'=2(VU^TU-X^TU+\lambda LV)$$
and extract a single *scalar* element from it by pre/post multiplying by $\{e_k\}$ vectors from the standard basis
$$F'_{ab} = e_a^TF'e_b \,=\, 2e_a^T(VU^TU-X^TU+\lambda LV)e_b$$
and then take the gradient of *that* with respect to $V$
$$F''_{ab} = \frac{\partial F'_{ab}}{\partial V}
= 2e_ae_b^TU^TU + 2\lambda Le_ae_b^T$$
By doing things this way, all of the following quantities are matrices with identical dimensions 
$$V,F',F''_{ab} \in {\mathbb R}^{N\times K}$$
If you want to see a different way to handle things, check out Magnus & Neudecker's book, "Matrix Differential Calculus"

Comment: I think that the result of $F^{''}_{ab}$ is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have a question about $F_{ab}^{''}$. How could Formula (28) be get from the $F_{ab}^{''}$ which you deduce it? For example, in $F_{ab}^{''}$ you deduce, the first term is $e_ae_b^T$, but the subscripts of the first term is 'bb' in Formula (28).