# How to solve $F''_{w_{ab}}$? I want to know the detailed calculation process of solving $F''_{w_{ab}}$.

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

There is a objective function:

$f(W)$ = $||W||_{2,1}$

For any element $w_{ab}$ in $W$, we apply $F_{w_{ab}}$ to denote the part of $f(W)$ which is only related to $w_{ab}$.

$F'_{w_{ab}}=(DW)_{ab}$

**$F''_{w_{ab}}=(D-D^{3}(W\odot W))_{aa}$,** (the main problem)

where $D_{ii}$=$\frac{1}{||w^i||_2}$, $\odot$ denotes the element-wise multiplication.

About $F_{w_{ab}}$: [why the second order derivative of F is equation (28)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217937/why-the-second-order-derivative-of-f-is-equation-28)

Note that: The norm $\|\cdot\|_{2,1}$ of a matrix $W\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is defined as

$$
\Vert W \Vert_{2,1} 
= \sum_{i=1}^n \Vert w^{i} \Vert_2
= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^m |w_{ij}|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$
where $w^i$ denotes $i^{th}$ row of $W$, $w_{ij}$ denotes a element of $W$.

**How to solve $F''_{w_{ab}}$? I want to know the detailed calculation process of solving the above formula.**

There some more explicit definition in the following papers (I gave the exact location.)

Some Related Papers:

[*Efficient and Robust Feature Selection via Joint $l_{2,1}$-Norms Minimization*](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3988-efficient-and-robust-feature-selection-via-joint-l21-norms-minimization.pdf)

[*Graph Regularized Nonnegative Matrix Factorization for Data Representation*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5674058)
(Look Page 10, APPENDIX A, PROOFS OF THEOREM 1, formulas (26), (27) and (28))

In [*Nonnegative matrix factorization by joint locality-constrained and $l_{2,1}$-norm regularization*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11042-017-4970-9.pdf), (Look Page 7, the Proof of Lemma 1: **Here, how to obtain the result of $F^{''}_{v_{ab}}$?**)

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Can you define $F_{w_{ab}}$ more explicitly?

Comment: I think the chance of getting a helpful response would be higher if the definition of $F_{w_{ab}}$ were included in the question.

Comment: This [detailed answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035198/derivative-of-1-2-mixed-norm/2037509#2037509) shows how to calculate the derivative of the mixed norm. The **_only_** difference is that you use the symbol $\|W\|_{2,1}$ whereas he uses $\|W\|_{1,2}$.  Oddly, neither symbol corresponds with the standard usage, at least [according to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2.2C1_and_Lp.2Cq_norms) Wikipedia.

Comment: Since $D\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ and $W\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times m},\,$ the product $D^3(W\odot W)\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times m}\,$ is well defined. However, your "main" equation
$$F_{ab}'' = D-D^3(W\odot W)$$ is dimensionally incompatible. You cannot subtract a rectangular matrix from a square one. It only exists if $m=n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$\eqalign{
b &= (W\odot W)\,1 \implies db=2(W\odot dW)1 \cr
B &= {\rm Diag}(b),\quad D = B^{-1/2},\quad E=e_a\varepsilon_b^T \cr
}$$
Write the $\{2,1\}$ norm in terms of $b$ and find its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \|W\|_{2,1} \cr&= b^{\odot 1/2}:1 \cr
df
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}b^{\odot-1/2}:db \cr
 &= b^{\odot-1/2}:(W\odot dW)1 \cr
 &= b^{\odot-1/2}1^T:(W\odot dW) \cr
 &= (b^{\odot-1/2}1^T\odot W):dW \cr
 &= B^{-1/2} W:dW \cr
F'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} &= B^{-1/2} W = DW \cr
F_{ab}' &= e_a^TF'\varepsilon_b = E:DW \cr
}$$
Now find the gradient of this last quantity.
$$\eqalign{
dF_{ab}'
 &= E:(D\,dW+dD\,W) \cr
 &= DE:dW + EW^T:dB^{-1/2} \cr
 &= DE:dW - \tfrac{1}{2}EW^T:B^{-3/2}dB \cr
 &= DE:dW - \tfrac{1}{2}{\rm diag}(D^3EW^T):db \cr
 &= DE:dW - {\rm diag}(D^3EW^T):(W\odot dW)1 \cr
 &= DE:dW - \big({\rm diag}(D^3EW^T)1^T\big)\odot W:dW \cr
 &= DE:dW - {\rm Diag}(D^3EW^T)W:dW \cr
 &= \Big(DE - D^3\,{\rm Diag}(EW^T)W\Big):dW \cr
F_{ab}'' = \frac{\partial F_{ab}'}{\partial W} &= DE - D^3\,{\rm Diag}(EW^T)W \cr
}$$
In the above, $1$ is a vector with all elements equal to one, $e_a$ is a vector from the standard basis for ${\mathbb R}^{n}$, the basis vector $\varepsilon_b$ is from ${\mathbb R}^{m}$, a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, e.g. 
$$A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
the symbol $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product, and Hadamard powers are denote as
$$A^{\odot 3}=A\odot A\odot A$$
The function $a={\rm diag}(A)$ extracts the diagonal elements of $A$ into a vector $a$

while the function ${\rm Diag}(A)$ sets the off-diagonal elements of $A$ to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: $b^{\odot -1/2}1^T \odot W = B^{-1/2}W$?  I think that this is wrong by computing.

Comment: Given any two vectors $(a,c)$ and a matrix $X$ convince yourself that
$$A = {\rm Diag}(a) \\C = {\rm Diag}(c) \\AXC = ac^T\odot X$$
Then let $\,\,c=1,\,\,a=b^{\odot p},\,\,X=W$

Comment: OK，I miscalculated. You're right.

Comment: I have three problems：First, $df=\tfrac{1}{2}b^{\odot-1/2}:db$?  Second, $\tfrac{1}{2}EW^T:B^{-3/2}dB=\tfrac{1}{2}{\rm diag}(D^3EW^T):db$? Third,  how to transform $E$ from Diag() to outside in $D^3\,{\rm Diag}(EW^T)W$?

Comment: Let $p\in{\mathbb R}$ and re-use $(a,A,X)$ from the previous comment. Then the following hints might help you resolve your issues. 
$$\eqalign{
1)\quad&f=a^{\odot p}:1 = A^p:I \cr
 &df=pA^{p-1}dA:I = pA^{p-1}:dA = pa^{\odot p-1}:da \cr
2)\quad&X:{\rm Diag}(a) =  {\rm diag}(X):a \cr
3)\quad&{\rm Diag}(AX) = {\rm Diag}(A)\,{\rm Diag}(X) = A\,{\rm Diag}(X) \cr
}$$